# When I use a Jenkinsbuild file in Jenkins to run a shell script, does it execute on master or slave?

Tags: python, jenkins

I am confused. I've setup Jenkins. I've setup a Master and a Slave node. I have a Jenkinsbuild file in my git repo, which is executed by the pipeline job. And in the Jenkinsbuild file I have lines like this:

```
 sh "docker build -t cd-demo ."
```

Where is this executed? Does this happen on the master or on the slave?

If I write a Python script, and I want to call it as a shell script, do I need to put the Python script on the master or on the slave?

Even more important: if I want to push a built Docker image to ECS, which machine needs to have AWS credentials, the master or the slave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your master has the executors, it will be the one to serve it. If you happen to define a label as answered by Elias22 , it will run on the least used node that contains such a label, (you have to set the label on your slave for this to work).

Regarding the credentials, these should be kept at the master. There is a plugin for aws credentials. The master is always the responsible for **keeping secrets secret**

If you are using aws credentials plugin from Cloudbees and using a Jenkinsfile with a pipeline, you might use the following in your pipeline. Consider that you have to set the credentials on the jenkins/credentials first.

```
node{ 
 label 'buildSlaveLabel'
}
stage("Im pushing docker image at this stage")
{
    withAWS(credentials:'TheNameYouSetUnderCredentialsInJenkins') {
        sh "docker-push.sh"
    }
}
```

This is similar to any other use of credentials by nodes, such as SCM (git , svn) , or other credentials usage.

It's master responsability to provide it to nodes.

However, you can always allow for the node to have its aws credentials somewhere accessible to anyone using the slave. (which I highly advise against, as there is no reason to do it)

Answer (score 0):

It will run on that node, which Jenkins thinks, is the best right now.

But you can define in your groovy-code on which node single steps or the whole pipeline should run, by the following code:

```
        node{
        label '<node-name>'            
             }
```

If you want to run python-code, you'll have to put it on every node, where you want to run that code.